# How to store binary data in Dynamo with boto?

Tags: boto, amazon-dynamodb

I can't determine from the docs/examples how to store/read binary data from DynamoDB using boto's dynamodb2. How is it done?

My guess was with an item value like `{ 'B': binary-data }` but that causes an error in the JSON encoder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It needs to be base 64 encoded into a string.

```
from base64 import b64encode
data = {'B': b64encode(binary_data)}
```

There is a library that can do this for you: [PynamoDB](https://github.com/jlafon/pynamodb).
The code which handles serialization to and from binary for Python 2 and 3 can be found [here](https://github.com/jlafon/PynamoDB/blob/devel/pynamodb/attributes.py#L92).

Disclaimer: I am the author of PynamoDB.

Comment: It does double-encoding unfortunately :/ any plans on fixing that?

Answer (score 15):

boto provides the Binary class to do this automatically:

```
from boto.dynamodb2.table import Table
from boto.dynamodb.types import Binary

Table('mytable').put_item({'hashkey': Binary('\x01\x02')})
```

Comment: FYI, to decode, get the item and use the `.value` member. e.g.: `item['hashkey'].value`